# Is it nessasary to call Session.removeAttribute when adding new attribute with same key

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

My question is about session management. I want to know if it is necessary to call remove Attribute when I want to add a new object with the same key.

Consider two below sample:

Sample One

```
session.setAttribute("person", new Student());
session.removeAttribute("person");
session.setAttribute("person", new Teacher());
```

Sample Two

```
session.setAttribute("person", new Student());
session.setAttribute("person", new Teacher());
```

Is it necessary to call the removeAttribute()?! If I don't call removeAttribute will the jdk garbage collect `new Strudent()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to call `removeAttribute()`.

Any (sane) implementation of a JEE web container will implement this functionality with some kind of `java.util.Map`. Sane implementations of `Map` will not keep a hidden reference to overwritten keys; this means that when a new entry uses the same key as an old one, the reference from the map structure to the old *value* will be erased. If no more references exist to the old value, it is elligible for garbage collection and will eventually get collected.